# Connect to mercurial via ssh on windows

Tags: windows, mercurial, ssh

Can anyone point me in the direction of a simple step by step guide as to how to connect to a mercurial repo via ssh on windows. Im really struggling to get my head around it, and so far i jus keep getting a string of errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this http://www.codza.com/mercurial-with-ssh-setup-on-windows

Comment: Use cygwin's OpenSSH instead of plink. It turned out to be 25 times faster in my case. Stdin/stdout pipes (which hg uses) are very slow in plink.

Answer (score 0):

Assumes: you have a putty suite installed, a ppk and using TortoiseHg.

Here is my original `c:\somerepo\.hg\hgrc` file:

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/someuser/somerepo
```

So what's happening with `ssh`?  Let's debug a pull statement, `hg pull --debug` on the command-line.  I noticed it is running `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\TortoisePlink.exe` instead of `ssh` to make the call:

```
PS C:\somerepo> hg pull --debug
pulling from ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/someuser/somerepo
running "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 hg@bitbucket.org "hg -R someuser/somerepo serve --stdio"
sending hello command
sending between command
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

So let's just reuse the call, add compression (yay!), non-interactive (batch) and our key:

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/someuser/somerepo

[ui]
ssh = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -C -batch -i "c:\keys\somekey.ppk"
```